# What is the life time of a database?

Tags: java, android, database

I am using android studio to make a calender application. I made a database to save an event.I was able to open the event as long as the Android Virtual Device was running but when I closed it and opened it again I would not open the event again. **Is it possible that the database remains as long as the AVD is running?**

[image]

Comment: `when I closed it and opened it again I would not open the event again` what do you mean! you should find your work if you successfully saved it! unless you uninstalled the app or cleared it's data or manually deleted db file or modified it's content!

Comment: Do you disconnect from db before leaving the app ? Write some code pls

Comment: You probably are not calling  SQLiteDatabase.close() method

Answer (score 0):

Well I can see in your snippet that you are doing your query and your data manipulation in the same class, if you'd had separated the responsibility away then the life of opening and closing a connection could have been easier.

You should have created a DatabaseFactory which sets up the connection to the database. Have simple methods like openConnection(string connectionString) Close() and query(string sql, string[] param).

Another class called DatabaseConsumer should basically open a connection, use the query, return the data however you want (ResultSet?), then close the connection after.

But to answer your question in terms of your design, you can just close the connection after your finished your while statement (res.moveToNext). Something like myDB.closeConnection() ?

edit : Implications of not closing a connection can leave the server holding that connection, some config value will say how many open connections your DB can handle. After a while the database will not allow the connection and give you an SQLServerException, boohoo.